# zlib continue inflate after Z_STREAM_END

Tags: zlib, inflate

How can I proceed with decoding after getting the status `Z_STREAM_END`. If you call `inflate ()` after `Z_STREAM_END`, then nothing changes.
I need to continue decoding after `Z_STREAM_END`. But the fact is that the dictionary is reset after receiving `Z_STREAM_END`. As a result, the next packet in deflate format is not decoded, only the first literal is decoded, and then `inflate()` returns -3. The dictionary should not be reset after `Z_STREAM_END`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to decode?

Comment: Solved the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

That means the compressed stream has ended. If for some reason you are expecting *another* compressed stream right after the one that just ended, then you will need to call `inflateInit()` or `inflateInit2()` again to restart the decompressor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I call inflateInit (), will the dictionary be reset?

Comment: Interesting, but after inflate () the function inflateGetDictionary () returns a dictionary of zero length.

Comment: Yes, the sliding window is reset.